# How to let the pageController control the UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uipagecontrol

I want a UIImageView swipe left, the UIImageView will change the image, at this time, the pageController +1, if swipe right, the pageContoller -1, and display the previous image... ...How can I implement it? Any simple code? thz u.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView. When the gesture recognizer triggers, you would check it's direction and then change images and update the pageController accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(next:)];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
swipeLeftRecognizer=nil;
[recognizer release];

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(prev:)];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
swipeRightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];
swipeLeftRecognizer=nil;
[recognizer release];
```